# Du-Bois- Reymond Function.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Please give me an example of a continuous function whose Fourier series diverges at a point. (given by Du Bois-Reymond).
thanks.

Comment: See [an example of a continuous function whose Fourier series diverges at a dense set of points](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14855/an-example-of-a-continuous-function-whose-fourier-series-diverges-at-a-dense-set) (see the end of user1119's answer for links to Du Bois-Reymond's original paper).

Comment: Is not there a difference between at a point and at a dense set of points?

Comment: Sure, but I suspect what Du Bois-Reymond does is to show that such a function can be constructed at any specified single point (this by itself was probably a new result) and then he uses Hankel's (then very new) method of condensation of singularities to obtain an example for a countable set set of points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're satisfied with a theoretical way of constructing such a function, the idea being to pile "bad" functions...

**Definitions:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a $2\pi$-periodic function.

- $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$ if $f$ is continuous
- $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ if $f$ is measurable and $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}|f(t)|\,dt<\infty$
- $\displaystyle\|f\|_{\infty}:=\sup_t|f(t)|$

Note that $C(\mathbb{T})\subset L^1(\mathbb{T})$.

If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ then its *Fourier coefficients* are defined by
$$
\hat{f}(k) := \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)e^{-ikt}\,dt\quad(k\in\mathbb{Z})
$$
The *Fourier series* of $f$ is then the [expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124951/sum-limits-k-in-mathbbz-versus-sum-limits-k-infty-infty)
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(k)e^{ikt}
$$
Its *symmetric partial sums* are noted
$$
s_nf(x) := \sum_{k=-n}^n\hat{f}(k)e^{ikx}\quad(n\geq0)
$$

> **Theorem (Du Bois Reymond):** There is a $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$ such that
>   $$
> \sup_n|s_nf(0)|=\infty
> $$
>   In particular, the Fourier series of $f$ diverges at $x=0$.

We need preliminary results in order to prove this.

> **Lemma 1:** Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$. Then
>   $$
> s_n f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x-t) D_n(t) \,dt
> $$
>
> where
>   $\begin{aligned}[t]
> D_n(t) :&= \sum_{k=-n}^n e^{ikt} \\
>         &= \frac{\sin( (n+1/2) t )}{\sin(t/2)} \quad (\textit{Dirichlet kernel})
> \end{aligned}$

**Proof:** We have
\begin{align*}
s_nf(x) &= \sum_{k=-n}^n \hat{f}(k) e^{ikx} \\
        &= \sum_{k=-n}^n \left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(t) e^{-ikt} \,dt \right) e^{ikx} \\
        &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(t) \sum_{k=-n}^n e^{ik(x-t)} \,dt \\
        &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x-t) \sum_{k=-n}^n e^{ikt} \,dt \\
        &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x-t) D_n(t) \,dt
\end{align*}

where
\begin{align*}
D_n(t) &= \sum_{k=-n}^n e^{ikt} \\
       &= e^{-int} \frac{e^{ i(2n+1)t }-1}{e^{it}-1} \\
       &= \frac{e^{ i(n+1)t }-e^{-int}}{e^{it/2} \left( e^{it/2}-e^{-it/2} \right)} \\
       &= \frac{e^{ i(n+1/2)t }-e^{ -i(n+1/2)t }}{\left( e^{it/2}-e^{-it/2} \right)} \\
       &= \frac{\sin( (n+1/2)t )}{\sin(t/2)}
\end{align*}

> **Lemma 2:** $\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|D_n(t)|\,dt\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$

**Proof:** This has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760462/if-d-m-is-the-mth-dirichlet-kernel-d-m-1-to-infty-as-m-to-infty/1760508#1760508).

> **Lemma 3:** $|s_nf(0)|\leq(2n+1)\|f\|_{\infty}$

**Proof:**
$$
|s_nf(0)|=\bigg|\sum_{k=-n}^n\hat{f}(k)\bigg|\leq\sum_{k=-n}^n|\hat{f}(k)|\leq(2n+1)\|f\|_{\infty}
$$

> **Lemma 4:** For all $\epsilon>0$ and all $k>0$ there exists $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$ and $n\geq1$ such that
>   $$
> \|f\|_{\infty}\leq\epsilon\quad\text{and}\quad|s_nf(0)|\geq k
> $$

**Proof:** Let's take
$$
f_n(t):=\frac{\epsilon \overline{D_n(-t)}}{1+|D_n(-t)|}
$$
where $n$ is to be chosen. Then $f_n\in C(\mathbb{T})$ and $\|f_n\|_{\infty}\leq\epsilon$. Finally,
\begin{align}
s_nf_n(0) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_n(0-t)D_n(t)\,dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\epsilon |D_n(t)|^2}{1+|D_n(t)|}\,dt\\
&=\epsilon\bigg(\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|D_n(t)|\,dt}_{\xrightarrow[(n \to \infty)]{}\,\infty} - \underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{|D_n(t)|}{1+|D_n(t)|}\,dt}_{\leq1}\bigg)\\
&\to\infty\quad(n\to\infty)
\end{align}
Choosing $n$ large enough we have $|s_nf_n(0)|\geq k$.

> **Proof of the theorem**

By lemma 4 we can recursively choose $f_k\in C(\mathbb{T})$ and positive integers $n_k$ such that
$$
\|f_k\|_{\infty}\leq2^{-k}\min_{1\leq j\leq k-1}\left(\frac{1}{2n_j+1}\right)\quad(\leq2^{-1}\text{ if }k=1)
$$
and
$$
|s_{n_k}f_k(0)|\geq k
$$
Also, we might assume that
$$
\bigg|s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}f_j+f_k\bigg)(0)\bigg|\geq\bigg|s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}f_j-f_k\bigg)(0)\bigg|
$$
since if it's false we can replace $f_k$ by $-f_k$. This has as an effect that
\begin{align}
\bigg|s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k}f_j\bigg)(0)\bigg| &\geq \frac{1}{2}\bigg|s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}f_j+f_k\bigg)(0)\bigg|+\frac{1}{2}\bigg|s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}f_j-f_k\bigg)(0)\bigg|\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg|s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}f_j+f_k\bigg)(0)\bigg|+\frac{1}{2}\bigg|-s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}f_j-f_k\bigg)(0)\bigg|\\
&\geq\frac{1}{2}\bigg|s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}f_j+f_k-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}f_j+f_k\bigg)(0)\bigg|\\
&=|s_{n_k}f_k(0)|\\
&\geq k
\end{align}
where the first inequality comes from the fact that if $A\geq B$ then $A\geq\frac{A+B}{2}$.

Now let $\displaystyle f:=\sum_{j\geq1}f_j$.

Since $\|f_j\|_{\infty}\leq2^{-j}$ for all $j$, this series converges uniformly and hence $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$.

Also, for all $k$,
$$
s_{n_k}f(0) = s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^kf_j\bigg)(0)+s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}f_j\bigg)(0)
$$

But we've seen that
$$
\bigg|s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{k}f_j\bigg)(0)\bigg| \geq k
$$
and by lemma 3 we have
\begin{align}
\bigg|s_{n_k}\bigg(\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}f_j\bigg)(0)\bigg| &\leq (2n_k+1)\bigg\|\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}f_j\bigg\|_{\infty}\\
&\leq (2n_k+1)\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}\|f_j\|_{\infty}\\
&\leq (2n_k+1)\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{-j}}{2n_k+1}\\
&=\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}2^{-j}\\
&\leq1
\end{align}
Hence $|s_{n_k}f(0)|\geq k-1$ which $\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: The definition of the L-infinity norm is not correct (top of post). It should depend on the essential supremum, not the ordinary supremum.